# Get counts of similar array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to count similar `array` values to get how many quantities of similar items there are in array. I managed to get the counts however I want to show every quantities in the array in HTML

```
var arr = ['Coke','Coke Diet','Pepsi','Sprite','Coke','Water'];
var obj = [];
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
   if (obj[arr[i]]) {
      obj[arr[i]]++;
   }
   else {
      obj[arr[i]] = 1;
   } 
}
```

I'm having a problem to render them in HTML without specifying what type of drink.

```
$('#items').append(obj.Coke)
```

How can I `.append(obj)` without saying what kind of drink I want to show?

I want to show something like -- `(quantity) (drink)`

```
2x Coke
1x Sprite
3x Water
```

[JSfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ao2pzzt9/)

**Edit --** both answers below works, but I have another question regarding this. How can I prevent rendering the same item when adding an item to array instead just want to update the quantity when you hit add button.

I've created a new fiddle for this follow up question.

End Result should look like --

```
1 Coke
2 Sprite
```

rather than

`1 Coke 
 1 Sprite
 2 Sprite`

[JsFiddle 2 sample](https://jsfiddle.net/fb9gb3s0/2/)

Comment: `var obj = []; ` should be `var obj = {};`

Comment: @hackerrdave I tried that as well but its not appending the counts unless i put `obj.Coke`

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you want to do - do you want to dynamically grab properties from `obj`?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: You can access values from object via `obj['Coke']` - so just iterate thru the keys and pass that value in to the obj - `obj[key]` where `key = 'Coke'`. Also see the answer added below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with below solution:

```
var arr = ['Coke','Coke Diet','Pepsi','Sprite','Coke','Water'];
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
   if (obj[arr[i]]) {
      obj[arr[i]]++;
   }
   else {
      obj[arr[i]] = 1;
   } 
}

show = function() {
  Object.keys(obj).map(function(drink){
    var info = obj[drink]+"x "+drink+"<br/>";
    $('#items').append(info)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works bril. I have a follow up question please see my original question. Trying to prevent rendering the same item everytime I hit add btn, It's probably because of the .append() but instead I just want to update the quantity rather than having the same items but different quantities each time it renders

Comment: Can you try with `$('#items').html(info)` instead of `.append()` method.

Comment: yeah did that and that will only add 1 item click, what I want is `(1) Coke, (2) Sprite` rather than `(1) Coke, (1)Sprite, (2) Sprite`

Answer (score 3):

First of all `obj` should be an object `{}` not an array `[]`.

Second, to loop through the keys of an object, use `Object.keys` like this:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    var str = obj[key] + "x " + key;
    $('#items').append(str);
}
```

**Note:**

If you don't want to use `forEach`, you can iterate through the object keys using a `for-in` like this:

```
for(var key in obj) {
    var str = obj[key] + "x " + key;
    $('#items').append(str);
}
```

**Example:**

In this example I used [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) because they're better.

```js
var arr = ['Coke','Coke Diet','Pepsi','Sprite','Coke','Water'];

var obj = arr.reduce(function(o, e) {
  if(o[e]) o[e]++;
  else o[e] = 1;
  return o;
}, {});

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  var str = obj[key] + "x " + key;
  $("<li></li>").text(str)
                .appendTo("#items");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="items"></ul>
```

**Edit:**

You can acheive what you asked in the edit of your question in two ways:

1. Every time the button get clicked, empty the `.cart` element and refill it with the new statistics. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/z02z51pm/.
2. When adding the item to the list, set a an ID (something like `count-of-Coke` ...), so when a new item is added, we only update the row of that item without affecting the other rows. This is very useful if the list is very big, because instead of emptying the `.cart` element and rebuild it from scratch, we only update the row of the item using that ID. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ppesc6ek/.

Note that I changed a bit of your code, havink an array to store the items and then count the items inside it every time, is a hell of a labor, what I did instead is get rid of those two arrays and replace them with the counter object directly, so when an item is added, we won't recount the items we already counted, but instead we will just increment the counter of that item (or create a new one if that item haven't been added yet).

Comment: can I ask?. what does this line do?. `if(o[e]) o[e]++;`

Comment: @KiRa It mean if `o[e]` is defined then increment its value. `o[e]` will be something like `o["Coke"]` which will be the counter for the Cokes!

Comment: Can I ask why you chose to do `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key)` instead of `for(var key in obj)`?

Comment: @ibrahim thanks for the explanation. I'm still learning `JS` :)

Comment: @fauxserious It's just to not use `for`, functional is better! I'll add it as a ote though!

Comment: Do you have a reference to why functional is better?

Comment: @fauxserious read [**this**](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter6.html). It's a great chapter about why functional is better!

Comment: I think it's better because it uses abstractions like `forEach`, `map` hides minimize the code and make it more readable.

Comment: @KiRa Here is a [**link**](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) to a great book, you may find it useful.

Comment: Something's to keep in mind when creating abstractions (or your own higher-level functions) is that they generally come at a performance cost, especially when you misuse them. For example, using .map() or .reduce() when you aren't really mapping or reducing. I think you can identify with that Ibrahim, based on some of your on previous answers ;). They key is to balance readability, maintainability and performance. There is not an "always better" approach.

Comment: Thanks, this works bril. I have a follow up question please see my original question. Trying to prevent rendering the same item everytime I hit `add` btn, It's probably because of the `.append()` but instead I just want to update the quantity rather than having the same items but different quantities each time it renders.

Comment: @MrNew See the **Edit** section above!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks, array was the first thing that comes in my head when I was coding it. I guess it was okay if the list is tiny but when it gets really big then it will be a problem. Amazing, the 2nd answer breaks if `drink name` has space `Coke Diet`, trying to add all items `(3) coke, (1) sprite` and subTotal is not adding up, they're stuck on default price `1.99`

Comment: @MrNew That's because I'm making an ID out of the name, but IDs must not have spaces `count-of-Diet Coke` is not valid. Here I fixed it by replacing the spaces with `-`. Check it here https://jsfiddle.net/ppesc6ek/4/!

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to comment back, that I've fixed that :) thanks. Really appreciate it.